# Generate JWT token not valid - java

Tags: java, jwt

I create a JWT token and if I go to the official site https://jwt.io/ and check its validity, then it shows that it is not valid.

Please tell me why it turns out that it is not valid?

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJKYWNrIiwiaWF0IjoxNjYwMDY3NjQ0LCJleHAiOjE2NjAxNTQwNDR9.yUqKI1t2xKVlhALUw12ie3DcpnGyXelcd7J-0qJ1FPg

```
        public class GeneratorJwt {
            
            public static void main(String[] args)  {

                Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();

                SecretKey key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);

                String jwtTokenKey = Encoders.BASE64.encode(key.getEncoded());

                String s = Jwts.builder()
                        .setClaims(claims)
                        .setSubject("Jack")
                        .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                        .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 86400000))
                        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, jwtTokenKey).compact();
                
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: How did you checked the JWT token on the external site? Specifically, what have you entered in the "your-256-bit-secret" field?

Comment: @Progman Yes, that's right.

Comment: A JWT token only verified with the public or the private key, Did you set any key for the verification on the https://jwt.io/  site?

Comment: @Zabihullah Alipour I created a token for a client based on its name. And this token is sent to the client. I saw this code here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doFx3-xfDN4&list=PLYZvWFacASF_4sL7xjZkfA-YNMAqk1TXn&index=7  Он также показывает, что код недействителен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly should not use HS256, which is a symmetric algorithm, meaning you have to give the secret key to clients for them to be able to validate the JWT. See the [JWT Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-best-practices/) article for this type of guidance.

Start with the most mainstream token signing algorithm of RS256 instead - here is some Java code of mine that uses it, via the highly respected [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home) library:

- [Token Issuing](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/test/java/com/mycompany/sample/tests/utils/TokenIssuer.java#L47)
- [Token Validation](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.java#L48)

In jwt.io you can then paste in the [token signing public key (JWK)](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/test/java/com/mycompany/sample/tests/utils/TokenIssuer.java#L38) to see the token validated. If you prefer, translate the same concepts to a different JWT library of your choice. See also [this blog post of mine](https://authguidance.com/jwt-access-token-validation/) which uses the jwt.io website.